# How to repeatedly call the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am displaying the following tableView :

[image]

I want: when i click on next(or Previous) button it should display SAME table with different images (next/Previous 10-images)..

as the number of images are dynamic i cant use detailedView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload the tableview using defferent data and, for reloading tableview use this code

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

Answer (score 4):

1) First remove all the elements from `array`(Array which you passed to the `table`).

2) Add the new elements into the array which you want on next & previous `button` clicked.

3) After that `reload` the `table data` using `[tbl reloadData];`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will Help:

```
- (void) loadDataToWebView {
    [yourDataSourceArray removeAllObjects];
    yourDataSourceArray = [self getNewdataToPopulate];
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSMutableArray *) getNewdataToPopulate{
    //write code to get new data to popualate in  your table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is not tested in Xcode so it may have some errors but this will help I guess
    #define RecordPerPage   10
    int pageNo, totalPage;
    NSMutableArray * totalRecord, * arrShow;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     totalPage = [totalRecord count]/RecordPerPage;
     if([totalRecord count]%RecordPerPage==0){
         totalPage++;
     }
}
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
     UIBarButtonItem * btn = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;
     //Next Button tag = 1
     if(btn.tag==1)
     {
        if(pageNo<totalPage)
           pageNo++;
        else{
              //Your code Here
            } 
     }
     else
     {
       if(pageNo>0)
           pageNo--;
        else{
              //Your code Here
            }
     }

     [arrShow removeAllObjects];

     int startVal, endVal;
     startVal = pageNo * RecordPerPage;
     endVal = startVal + RecordPerPage;
     startVal++;

     for(int i=startVal; i<endVal; i++)
     {
         if([totalRecord count]>i)
             break;

         [arrShow addObject:[totalRecord objectAtIndex:i]];
     }
}
```

Comment: ya thanks.. i have written something similar code.. but in the same button i want to reload the default tableview.. how to do that?  and if im reloading in this function then only first element is executed again n again..       -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Are you sure your changing the values in arrShow and reloading tableView after that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 This block of code will help you

    - (IBAction)previous:(id)sender
{
      self.selectedindex--;
    if (self.selectedindex==0) {
        prev.enabled=NO;
    }
    else{
        prev.enabled=YES;
        next.enabled=YES;

    }
   //get the selected indexed data from the array    

//reload the table 
[Tableviewname reloaddata];       

}
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    self.selectedindex++;
    if (self.selectedindex>0) {
        prev.enabled=YES;
    }
      if (self.selectedindex==49) {
        next.enabled=NO;
    }
 //get the selected indexed data from the array    

//reload the table 
[Tableviewname reloaddata];       
}
```